# Starting a web app now which will use python that later this need to embed nicely into a Drupal site?

Tags: python, drupal

This week, I want to start a web mapping and data visualization site for my work.

Unfortunately, I just found out my work place will be using Drupal in a few months down the road. (Most of my web development experience is with App Engine.)

My problem is that I need to make sure my web application embeds nicely into the larger Drupal site that outside consultants plan to make.

I am most comfy with Python, and I was expecting to use the Python-Django combo instead. There are important python libraries and modules I must have that cant be found or re-written in PHP.

I was thinking I will avoid all django on the web pages so things dont get confusing when the Drupal switch is made.

I will have the javascript on the web page make calls to python on the server which then spits out JSON data, and I think this will stay the same even after the Drupal switch.

Does this make sense?

Any general or specific suggestions that may guide me are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "...that cant be found or re-written in PHP." I'm incredulous. I doubt very much that there is anything that can be written in python (or any Turing complete language) that cannot also be written in PHP.

Comment: For example, lets say a user requests some statistical summary of the data, on the server I want to do this data crunching in python using the numpy library. Perhaps PHP has something like that? I am unsure. Also there may be times when I wanted to use python's imaging library PIL. But most importantly I want to re-use lots of my own data analysis code. Thanks. Perhaps I should just have PHP call the python scripts?

Comment: Sorry, I was nitpicking there. I'd go with calling the python scripts from PHP. The only catch is that they may not want to keep python after the switch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write API calls and utilize Drupal Services module, you can hook into just about anything and send/receive JSON/XML data.

Comment: Thank you for helping direct me in my research!